# Vaadin table with column widths according to the content width

Tags: width, vaadin

In Vaadin, a HorizontalLayout gives each component exactly the space it needs as long as there is enough of it and not more.

In a table created with a BeanItemContainer however, all the columns have the same width. Because the table content is loaded dynamically, the width is different each time and different PCs have different font sizes, we don't want to specify a fixed width in pixels.

How can we tell the row to behave like a html table or a HorizontalLayout in that it gives each row the right width, not more and not less?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this only with CSS Rule:

```
.v-table td:last-child {
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

Chrome>=4, Firefox>=3.5, Opera>=9.6, Safari>=3.2, IE>=9

Comment: Unfortunately I don't use Vaadin anymore so I cannot verify for myself if this answer is correct, if you provide me with a screenshot to prove that it works I will accept it.

Comment: I would, but it is sensitive data in it. Maybe another channel to contact?

Comment: OK then I just trust you to have checked it :-)

Answer (score 4):

setColumnWidth(-1) should activate auto-scaling. Though this is usually the default (even with BeanItemContainers, so I'm surprised you aren't seeing that behaviour automatically.
A related concept, possibly worth you pursuing is setSizeUndefined() which is a method of the Sizeable interface.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me that you are looking for the expand ratio. It works like the expand ratio of HorizontalLayout.

Have a look at https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Table.html#setColumnExpandRatio%28java.lang.Object,%20float%29 for more information.

```
Table oTable = new Table();
oTable.addContainerProperty("First name", String.class, null);
oTable.addContainerProperty("Last name", String.class, null);
oTable.addContainerProperty(YEAR_PROPERTY, Integer.class, null);

oTable.addItem(new Object[] { "Nicolaus","Copernicus",new Integer(1473) }, new Integer(1));
oTable.addItem(new Object[] { "Tycho",   "Brahe",     new Integer(1546) }, new Integer(2));
oTable.addItem(new Object[] { "Giordano","Bruno",     new Integer(1548) }, new Integer(3));
oTable.addItem(new Object[] { "And this is a very very long cell", "Newton", new Integer(1643) }, new Integer(4));

oTable.setSizeFull();
oTable.setColumnExpandRatio(YEAR_PROPERTY, 1.0f);
```

Edit: if you set the expandratio for one cell (for example the last one) all others just take their space needed. This could be a workaround for your requirement.

If you comment out the last added item, you'll see that the first column only takes the space needed.

Comment: The expand ratio does not fix the problem unfortunately. The expand ratio gives an object more space than it really needs but I want it to have just the bare minimum (but not less as well).

Comment: I've added an example in my previous post.

Comment: With Vaadin version 6.7.2, the expand ration 1.0f just takes all the abundant space. The other columns don't get re-sized. What we want is that the columns expand so their values are completely shown.